# Ansible JSON Query sabznbd Linux tarball only, not the whole source code

Tags: ansible

I am trying to download the latest version of sabnzbd from Github API via Ansible. I know how to get the whole tarball like so;

```
---
- name: Install sabnzbd
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Get URL of latest sabnzbd
    ansible.builtin.uri:
      url: https://api.github.com/repos/sabnzbd/sabnzbd/releases/latest
      body_format: json
      return_content: true
      remote_src: yes
    register: json_reponse

  - name: Download sabnzbd tarball
    ansible.builtin.get_url:
      url: "{{ json_reponse.json.tarball_url }}"
      dest: /tmp
    register: sabnzbd_tarball
```

However, I would rather just get the `*src.tar.gz` Linux tarball to keep the directory as clean as possible.

I have tried;

```
---
- name: Install sabnzbd
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Get latest version
    uri:
      url: "https://api.github.com/repos/sabnzbd/sabnzbd/releases/latest"
      return_content: yes
    register: github_response

  - set_fact:
      binary_asset_url: "{{ github_response.json|json_query(query) }}"
    vars:
      query: "[? browser_download_url=='[*]]-src.tar.gz'"
      
  - debug:
      var: binary_asset_url
```

Just to see if I can get the URL, but I can't. I know I can use a shell one liner, but it's not as clean. I also would like to understand how to query json better by seeing this in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't stuck on using query you could just select the attribute using a search like this.

```
$ cat stack.yml
---
- name: Install sabnzbd
  hosts:
    localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Get URL of latest sabnzbd
    ansible.builtin.uri:
      url: https://api.github.com/repos/sabnzbd/sabnzbd/releases/latest
      body_format: json
      return_content: true
      remote_src: yes
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: json_response

  - name: Debug json_response
    debug:
      msg: "{{ (json_response.json.assets | selectattr('browser_download_url', 'search', 'src.tar.gz') | list | first).browser_download_url }}"
```

Yielding:

```
$ ansible-playbook stack.yml

PLAY [Install sabnzbd] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Get URL of latest sabnzbd] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Debug json_response] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "https://github.com/sabnzbd/sabnzbd/releases/download/3.7.0/SABnzbd-3.7.0-src.tar.gz"
}
```

Comment: I added that into a `set_fact` so I could use it, thanks for the help. Any tips on where I could learn such Kung Fu?